# Weird Array issue

Tags: c#, arrays

So I am writing a C# console application. I have a text file that I want to send to a database. The plan is to have multiple text files and only one insert. Everything seems to go fine for the first line. Once I get to the 2nd line the array thinks it only has a length of 2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace UKImporter
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\out\output.txt");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of writeLines2.txt =:");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string sellername, sku, date1, quantity1, date2, asin, date3, date4, FNSKU;
            char[] tabs = { '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t',  };
            string[] words = line.Split(tabs);
            sellername = words[0];
            sku = words[1];
            date1 = words[2];
            quantity1 = words[3];
            date2 = words[4];
            asin = words[5];
            date3 = words[6];
            date4 = words[7];
            FNSKU = words[8];
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
            UKDataBLL u = new UKDataBLL();
            //u.AddToDatabase(sku, DateTime.Now, Convert.ToInt16(quantity1), DateTime.Now, asin, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, FNSKU);

            foreach (string s in words)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
}
```

Edit Here is some text of the file

`A2LQ9QFN82X636 ACD_fivecrowns  6/1/11 5:30 0   6/1/11 5:30 B00000IV35  6/1/11 5:30 6/1/11 5:30 X0000PGTT9`

`A2LQ9QFN82X63  ACD_caylus_magna_carta  6/1/11 5:30 0   6/1/11 5:30 B000N3SOUM  6/1/11 5:30 6/1/11 5:30 X0000PGM23`

`A2LQ9QFN82X63  AMX_JrSpaceHelmet-LBL   6/1/11 5:30 0   6/1/11 5:30 B0008F6WMM  6/1/11 5:30 6/1/11 5:30 X0000PQBUL`

Comment: post the content of that file

Comment: Silly question, but you know the second line has tabs, yes?  Opening the file in binary mode will verify this (should see 11 / 0B) listed on that row

Comment: You are referring to the lines array?

Comment: No need to post the whole file, but a few lines (copy pasted) would help to investigate/reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Joy for split method you just need to pass Split('\t') param. It will "cut" string when tab found. Besides you dont need to create char array for split method, you can write it as params Split('\t',';','|').

Comment: @billink Your comment is silly.

Comment: @Joe: the posted data sample is pretty useless. Post (copy paste) 2 or 3 lines, without wordwrap. Better add empty lines between them.

Comment: Your 3rd line is different from the other two, notice the first word? It seems to have an underscore in place of a tab. A quick fix might be `line.Split('\t', '_')` but you do have to look at your data specs.

Comment: @renuiz why would my comment be silly?  The code expects a tab delimited input file. The code for line 2 is behaving as if there are only 2 tabs. Either the logic was incorrect or the data is incorrect and given that it worked for the initial line, it lead me to believe the data was in error.  Answer I supplied below verifies the processing logic is sound (although it could be improved as others have commented)

Comment: @Henk I created this file in c. I could post the c code, however I don't think it is worth while That `_` is really apart of the second word and is just a typo.

Comment: But did you copy paste the data lines? It's such a waste of time to look at something you just typed in or edited. I'm leaving this.

Comment: @Henk whoa No I changed it by accident when I was placed ` in front of it. That is copy from my text file. However would not change the fact the at the second line it went for an array of 9 to an array of 2 before it touched the third line, the line in question. On top of that if my code worked it be able to read the until the first tab of the third line. There is really no reason to get snarky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the above code, I created a simple output file step that met your intended structure and your code does correctly parse the file out.  Your issue appears to be based on the data

```
    string[] content = new string[] { "a\tb\tc\td\te\tf\tg\th\ti", "a\tb\tc\td\te\tf\tg\th\ti" };
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\sandbox\output.txt", content);
```

Comment: I am confused @billinkc why would I try and output what I am reading in?

Comment: I was simply providing code that generates the expected file format.  Running that verifies your main logic is correct.  Instead it is the data in the file that does not meet the template format.

Answer (score 3):

You only need

```
 string[] words = line.Split('\t');
```

And then you have to verify that the contents and your operation match, a crude idea:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Trace.Assert (words.Count == 9);
```

Comment: I believe you mean words.Length ==9, which I tried and it giving an error on the second time through.

Comment: And what is your debugger telling you?

Comment: I am a little confuse what you are refering to. I know I have an Output from my debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The tabs parameter to the split only needs to have one tab character.   You are telling it all of the possible values to split on.   As written, you are telling it to split on a tab or a tab or and so on.

It is possible that the second line is not in the correct format.

Can you send a copy of a couple of lines from the import file?

Answer (score 1):

I dont really see why you need to specify all those tab characters in the split method.

Just do something like this:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] columns= line.Split('\t');
    if (columns.Length != 9) // Or how many colums the file should have.
        continue; // Line probably not valid

    // Now access all the columns of the line by using 
    // columns[0], columns[1], etc
}
```